# How could I send a string message to a specific client from a server using sockets in java?

Tags: java

I want to send data to my connected clients, but I want to send the message only to one specific user. I don't know how to accomplish this. Do I have to use the client's IP address or what? I'm programming in Java with sockets.

Comment: Did you already established a Socket Connection between a client and a server?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please consult [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question accordingly.

Comment: check this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: yes, Everything works from client_to_server, But now I want to send data from server to client and I want to send the data to a specific cliente for ex: the client with the ip 192.168.0.2 I will send a message and so on.

Comment: I established the connection with between client and server and it works fine, but now I want to send data to a specific client from a server.

Comment: Grammar fixes, removed erroneous tag

Comment: appect method returns Socket Object, that object is actuall y a conntion btw you and client. All communication take place thorugh that object. ServerSocket is just to accept or reject request from client. For communication you need to save that object(return by accept()) some where in collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add connected connection in some collection.

```
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
map.put("someKey", client);
```

when you have to send message to any specific client. just get his connection from map by giving its key.

```
Socket clnt = map.get("someKey");
```

// further processing.

in `c#` you can use dictionary in place of maps.

Comment: make sure, you key is unique, otherwise its gonna over-write the already existing object in map.

Comment: its good if you use "client.getInetAddress().toString() " as a key. every client gonna have different address, so overwrite can be avoided by doing this. But you need to keep track of IPs :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of the clients that connect to your server. Most likely using a client ID with a Key/Value collection (try looking up Map).

Comment: Same you can put in as comment